# Stored procedure query for selecting values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a Test table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
[TestId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TestName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[isDelete] [bit] NOT NULL,
```

and Questions table as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions](
[Qid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Tid] [int] NOT NULL,
[Qtype] [int] NOT NULL,
[Question] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[isDelete] [bit] NULL,
```

Questions table stores all the questions for each test with Tid as foreign key.

I want to write a stored procedure to fetch TestName, TestId and number of questions in each test in a single stored procedure. But I am unable to get this.

Comment: And what problem have you encountered with this? Please show your work.

Comment: This looks like a test or homework question... Please try to find a solution on your own, show your code and ask about specific issues. SO is not a *do my work* platform. One hint: For pure queries you should prefer a `VIEW` or an *inlined table valued function*. A SP is meant **to do** something.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the stored procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procGetNumberofQuestionsForTest]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT T.[TestId], T.[TestName], COUNT(Q.[Qid]) AS NumberOfQuestions
    FROM [dbo].[Test] T
    JOIN [dbo].[Questions] Q ON Q.Tid = T.TestId
    GROUP BY T.[TestId], T.[TestName]
END
```

If you want to get the result for specific Test, then pass the parameter as `@TestId INT` and add the `WHERE` clause as `WHERE T.[TestId] = @TestId` before the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (table create, insert, proc creation and execution included);

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
[TestId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TestName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[isDelete] [bit] NOT NULL)
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions](
[Qid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Tid] [int] NOT NULL,
[Qtype] [int] NOT NULL,
[Question] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[isDelete] [bit] NULL
)
go

 insert into [dbo].[Test]
 values('test #1',1,0)
 go
 insert into [dbo].[Questions]
 values(1,1,'what is life',0)
 go
 create proc dbo.MyInfo

 as

select 
    t.TestName,
    t.TestId,
    [No Questions]=COUNT(q.Qid)
from 
    [dbo].[Test] t
inner join
    [dbo].[Questions] q on t.TestId=q.Qid
group by
    t.TestName,
    t.TestId
go
exec dbo.MyInfo
go
```

Comment: This should not be a SP, rather a VIEW or an *inline table valued function...* And - as written in other comments before - you should *encourage students to do their homework*.

Comment: No technical reason that it cannot be an SP. I'd have it as a view personally but you don't know the use case. I've answered the question. I've worked on numerous commercial projects without a view ever being created and actually have SPs do that duty also.

Comment: Yes, I know these projects too. This was the good approach in older times, where SQL-Server did not know *inline TVF*, which is a parameterized view. Of course this *can be a SP*, but there are many obvious (technical) reasons against, mainly missing inlineability (indexes!) and the clumsy approaches to *use* the result of a SP in the next step. This is *old procedural thinking* and should not be used for new projects. If you really need a SP, why ever, you can stil use the iTVF and wrap it with a SP.

Comment: The SP obvisouly takes advantage of any indexes on the tables so that isn't a valid point. The user asked to return data from an SP and that's what they have been provided with.

Comment: Well, I know this ... But try to use the result of a SP in a join ... This is *outdated* thinking since the iTVF has been introduced.